# Question about a paper on Calculating All Possible Regressions

Tags: regression

I am currently reading the paper "Computational Efficiency in All Possible Regressions" by Liu and it mentions the following.
[image]

A quick explanation of what I understand: We have a set of $k$ variables. $\Omega$ denotes the set of these variables, $\Omega_2$ denotes the set of the variables already in the model and $\Omega_1$ denotes the set of variables to be added in the model.

[Edit - Equations]

**Equation (2.1)**
$$\Theta_{i_1,i_2,...,i_m} = SSE\left(\{x_i\}_{i\in\Omega_2}\right) - SSE\left(\{x_i\}_{i\in\Omega}\right) = SSR\left(\{x_i\}_{i\in\Omega_1} \mid \{x_i\}_{i\in\Omega_2}\right)$$

**Question 1**
From the definition in (2.1), I understand that $\Theta_{i_1,i_2,...,i_m}$ is the difference between the Sum of Squares due to Error (SSE) of the current model (containing $\Omega_2$) and the full model (containing $\Omega$, i.e. all the available variables). The author then says that this is equal to the "extra Sum of Squares due to Regression for adding $\{x_i\},i\in\Omega_1$, given the variables $\{x_i\}, i\in\Omega_2$ are already in the model."  How do we arrive in this equality?

**Question 2**
When we are to add one variable, i.e. $\Omega_1 = \{j\}$, then $\Theta_j = b_j^2/c_{jj}$. Again, how can one prove this? I noticed that this quantity is similar to the t-statistic $t = \frac{\hat{\beta_j}}{\sqrt{\hat{V}\left(\hat{\beta_j}\right)}} = \frac{\hat{\beta_j}}{S\sqrt{c_{jj}}}$ which is used when testing the null hypothesis $H_0: \beta_j = 0$

Comment: Hi, there are blind and visually impaired users of this 
site who interact with it using screen readers. The screen 
readers can't handle the equation in your screenshot. 
Please edit the post to include the equation as LaTeX. If 
it helps, we have some 
[resources on using LaTeX on Cross Validated](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1605/155836).

Comment: It seems you're talking about whats often called *all subsets regression* or sometimes *best subsets regression* (with all the issues that entails, ahem). e.g. see (i) https://webspace.maths.qmul.ac.uk/b.bogacka/SM_I_2013_LecturesWeek_10.pdf or (ii) https://online.stat.psu.edu/stat501/lesson/10/10.3 which discuss this topic ... that terminology may help you locate more relevant resources (including posts here)

Comment: @Glen_b Indeed I am conducting research on this topic. I will look into your suggestions, thank you.

Comment: Question 1: Not sure whether I miss something here, but to me the authors' statement looks like an interpretation of the definition. I don't think there's anything to show.

Comment: @ChristianHennig The author basically describes the second part of the equation; they describe SSR. My question is how does one begin from the difference of the two SSE's and arrive at the SSR of a conditional model?

Comment: @Fib the links were just to provide evidence of the terminology usage (and so you could double check that what I thought you were talking about was in fact what those terms refer to); they were not themselves intended as specifically recommended readings on the topic.

Comment: @Glen_b Got it thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I have the answer for Question 2.

We have that

$$t_{n-k-1} = \frac{\hat{\beta_j}}{\sqrt{\hat{V}\left(\hat{\beta_j}\right)}} = \frac{\hat{\beta_j}}{S\sqrt{c_{jj}}}$$

where

$$S^2 =\frac{SSE}{n-k-1}$$

Note that $t_{n-k-1}$ is the statistic for the $t$-test for the hypothesis below.

I will denote the full model of $k$ variables as $M$ and the current model with the $\Omega_2$ variables as $M_2$. Of course, $M_2 \subseteq M$.

Then,

$$\Theta_{i_1,i_2,...,i_m} = SSE\left(\{x_i\}_{i\in\Omega_2}\right) - SSE\left(\{x_i\}_{i\in\Omega}\right) = SSE_2 - SSE$$

We assume that the current model $M_2$ excludes only one variable, say $j$, from the full model $M$ (i.e.$\beta_j  = 0$), and that the rest of the variables with coefficients $\beta_i, i\neq j$ are unrestricted.

We also notice that

$$ \Theta_j = SSE_2 - SSE \implies \frac{ \Theta_j}{S^2} = \frac{SSE_2 - SSE}{S^2} = \frac{SSE_2 - SSE}{\frac{SSE}{n-k-1}} \sim F_{1,n-p} $$

Which means that $\frac{ \Theta_j}{S^2}$ is the $F$-statistic for testing the hypothesis

$$
H_0: \beta_j = 0 , \beta_i \text{ unrestricted } \forall i \neq j \left(M_2\right)
$$
$$
H_1: \beta_i \text{ unrestricted } \forall i  \left(M\right)
$$

Also,

$$
F_{1,n-k-1} \equiv t^2_{n-k-1} = \frac{ \left(\hat{\beta_j} - \beta_{j_\left(0\right)} \right)^2}{S^2c_{jj}} = \frac{ \hat{\beta_j}^2}{S^2c_{jj}}
$$

Finally,

$$
\frac{\Theta_j}{S^2} =  \frac{ \hat{\beta_j}^2}{S^2c_{jj}} \implies 
\Theta_j =  \frac{ \hat{\beta_j}^2}{c_{jj}}
$$

Edit:

I believe what I wrote in the last two lines is not entirely correct. It is true that if

$$ X \sim t_{n-k-1} \implies X^2 \sim F_{1,n-k-1}$$

However, it is **NOT** generally true that if

$$ X \sim F_{1,n-k-1} \text{ and } Y \sim F_{1,n-k-1} \text{ then } X \equiv Y$$

which is what I have used for the result. Does anyone have a hint on this?